# Real-time synchronization of PNG image positions on HTML5 Canvas using Socket.IO

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm working on a drawing application that allows the creator of a room to draw on an HTML5 Canvas, and the drawings are updated in real-time for other users in the room. The creator can also add and drag PNG images onto the canvas. However, I'm having trouble synchronizing the new positions of the dragged images in real-time for other users in the room.

Here's the relevant code:

Client-side:

```
function onMouseMove(e) {
    // ...
    if (isCreator()) {
        const selectedImage = placedImages.find((img) => img.selected);
        if (selectedImage) {
            selectedImage.x = mouseX - offsetX;
            selectedImage.y = mouseY - offsetY;
            requestAnimationFrame(redrawCanvas);
        }
    }
}

function onMouseUp(e) {
    drawing = false;
    socket.emit('mouseUp', { sessionId });

    if (isCreator()) {
        const selectedImage = placedImages.find((img) => img.selected);
        if (selectedImage) {
            selectedImage.selected = false;
            socket.emit('updateImagePosition', { id: selectedImage.id, x: selectedImage.x, y: selectedImage.y });
        }
    }
}

socket.on('updateImagePosition', ({ id, x, y }) => {
    const image = placedImages.find((img) => img.id === id);
    if (image) {
        image.x = x;
        image.y = y;
        requestAnimationFrame(redrawCanvas);
    }
});
```

```
function updateImage(socket, data) {
  const roomID = findRoomByCreator(socket.id);
  if (!roomID) return;
  const image = rooms[roomID].drawingData.find((img) => img.type === 'image' && img.id === data.id);
  if (image) {
      image.x = data.x;
      image.y = data.y;
      socket.to(roomID).emit('updateImagePosition', data);
  }
}
```

When the room creator moves the image, its new coordinates must be sent to the server via a socket, which must then send a coordinate update message to all users in the room using the `socket.to(roomID).emit('updateImagePosition', { id, x, y) method });.`

When this message is received, other users must update the image coordinates on their screens using the `placedImages.find((img) => img.id === id).x = x; placedImages.find((img) => img.id === id).y = y; requestAnimationFrame(redrawCanvas);` where placedImages is an array of images to display on the canvas.

Comment: your emiting updateImage, whilst listening for updateImagePosition, which is it

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I fixed it, but it didn't help? Can you suggest more options?

Comment: cant tell without all the code, but you changing `image.y = data.y;` etc but then just sending back `data`